# Running a query to fetch data until it gets NULL data along with its depth

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I need a query to run the select statement until it has NULL value. I can get this using while loop but my case is little different.

I have two tables AB and XY, AB will have the father and XY will have the child. The link between two tables is `AB.Code=XY.Father`

The child item may be a father to other child items too.

In the image that I have attached, A00002 is the father to item A00006 and A00010. Where A00010 is the father to item BSCR001 and BSCR002. And BSCR002 is the father for items C00001 - C00006 and the depth end here.

I need the result to be listed in this order along with the depth as present on the right side in the image which is A00002 starts with the depth 1 as this is the beginning and A00006 and A00010 falls in depth 2 which is the child of A00002. BSCR001 and BSCR002 at depth 3 which is the child of A00010 and C00001 - C00006 at depth 4 which are the child of BSCR002.

This loop and depth have to be increased until the result returns NULL value.
I haven't used SQL default functions until now but I know that this can be attained using the SQL functions.

Can anyone help me with this query?

[image]

Comment: Instead of image, provide your data, table structure and your expected output

Comment: Hi Kannan, i have attached the image of my tables and i need the results as like the image containing the Item codes and the Depth listed at the right

Comment: I am requesting u to put input data as text

Comment: Hi Gopi, you should consider single table for parent and child elements as they are similar entity. Just like Employee and Manager details can be put together in same table dbo.Employees. We can find an employee's manager by ManagerID in dbo.Employees table. Finally, to get hierarchical data with depth, you can use Recursive CTE.

Comment: Hi kannan, My input parameter will be the first parent which is A00002

Comment: It looks like you are building a recursive data structure. You can do this without the need for recursive SQL by using a "nested set" model. Perhaps try that? If you can search for "SQL nested set" you will certainly find how to do this. Good luck!